# jekyll passing variable to form page

Tags: variables, parameters, jekyll

I try to find a way to create a single booking form with jekyll.
I got for instance a button for booking at my tour details page.

When user click that button, I would love to know if there's a way to pass parameters to the booking page in order to display for example the name -- prices -- etc... of the tour.

I can't figure out how or even if its possible. Anyone clever enough for pointing me the right direction( if there's one) ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, but as Jekyll is static, you have to do this on client side.

Explanation.

#### The tour page (`tour.html`):

```
---
title: tours
layout: page
tour:
  name: Flying with eagles
  description: text here
  price: 120€
---
{% capture url %}n={{ page.tour.name | uri_escape }}&p={{ page.tour.price | uri_escape }}{% endcapture %}

<h2>{{ page.tour.name }} ({{ page.tour.price }}) - <a href="tour-form.html?{{ url }}">Book me for this tour!</a></h2>

<p>{{ page.tour.description }}</p>
```

Note that we use page variables to store values like name and price, but you can hard code this in the page body:

```
<h2>{{ page.tour.name }} ({{ page.tour.price }}) - <a href="tour-form.html?{{ url }}">Book me for this tour!</a></h2>
```

then becomes :

```
<h2>Flying with eagles (120€) - <a href="tour-form.html?n=Flying%20with%20eagles&amp;p=120%E2%82%AC">Book me for this tour!</a></h2>
```

#### the form (`tour_form.html`) :

```
---
title: tour form
layout: page
---

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="tourName" value="">
<input type="text" name="tourPrice" value="">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
// this script will automatically fill name and price fields 
// depending on what's passed in the url
var fillForm = function () {
    var queryString = document.location.search.split("+").join(" ");
    var params = {}, tokens, re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(queryString)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    if (params.n == undefined && params.p == undefined){
        // no value in the query string
        // here you have to manage this use case : redirect or print a message to user
    }else{
        // filling form fields with query string values
        document.getElementsByName('tourName')[0].value = params.n;
        document.getElementsByName('tourPrice')[0].value = params.p;
    }
} ();
</script>
```

This form is automatically filled with parameters passed from `tour.html`.

It can then be pointed to a form service like http://forms.brace.io/, http://www.jotform.com/ or any form service to deliver submitted datas.

Note: some services need a callback page to redirect to when the form is submitted.
You then need to make another page (eg: `thankyou.html`) in witch you'll have to parse and present url passed datas to user.